# Activity not getting started until orientation changes

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on Ice cream sandwich and at a point in my application on click of a button i start a new activity by using startActivity and passing the intent but the activity does not get started until i change the orientation of device. On changing orientation the activity automatically starts.

Just before starting this activity i have used android keyboard. i have added android:configchanges=orientation|uimode for all the activities in my application.

Cannot share the code. Some inputs would be of great help.

Comment: I have the similar issue. When I check in logcat it shows "Starting activity..." but "Displayed activity..." log is not shown. Usually whenever any activity starts, it shows both the logs.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use the logcat in the onCreate method of your new activity???
That could be help you a lot.

Comment: as a matter of fact the oncreate method is not called

Answer (score -1):

It's likely your activity is starting right away and being shown differently on orientation change.  Dig deeper into your logs or add more logging so you can see where your app is running into problems on first start.

Comment: as a matter of fact the oncreate method is not called

Comment: These downvotes are ill advised.  These are both fair answers given the level of effort to the question.  They are honest attempts to help, and the asker indicates that additional digging did indeed uncover more information.